# Scraping text from unordered lists using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python and beautiful soup to scrape information from a web page. I am interested in the following section of source code:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="/" title="Return to the home page">Home</a><span 
class="sprite icon-delimiter"></span></li>
<li><a href="/VehicleSearch/Search/Mini" title="View our range of Mini 
vehicles">Mini</a><span class="sprite icon-delimiter"></span></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/VehicleSearch/Search/Mini/Countryman" 
title="View our range of Mini Countryman">Countryman</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to extract the text of the unordered list bullets, i.e. 'Home', 'Mini' and 'Countryman' (which are also all links).

My closest try so far was by doing:

```
for ul in soup.findAll('ul', class_='breadcrumb'):
    print(ul.find('a').contents[0])
```

But this only found the 'Home' link and not the other two. How can I find all three link texts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add inner loop for link text:

```
for ul in soup.findAll('ul', class_='breadcrumb'):
    for link in ul.findAll('a'):
        print(link.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a css descendant combinator selector to retrieve the li tags within the class?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html ='''
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="/" title="Return to the home page">Home</a><span 
class="sprite icon-delimiter"></span></li>
<li><a href="/VehicleSearch/Search/Mini" title="View our range of Mini 
vehicles">Mini</a><span class="sprite icon-delimiter"></span></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/VehicleSearch/Search/Mini/Countryman" 
title="View our range of Mini Countryman">Countryman</a></li>
</ul>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.breadcrumb li')]
print(items)
```