# How can I scrape the xpath for each link in the `<ul>`?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a program that writes code for me. Imagine that I have a `<ul>` list on a website and I need to scrape all the xpath selectors for each element on that list. Is there an easy way to tell python to grab the xpath selectors for all of the elements in the `<ul>`?

For example we have this `<ul>`:

```
  <ul id="test">
    <li><a href="#">Zurich</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Geneva</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Winterthur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lausanne</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lucerne</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And I have this code in python:

```
ul= driver.find_elements_by_id('test')

for element in ul:
    selector = **find the xpath/selector**
    text = element.text
```

How can I scrape the xpath for each link in the `<ul>`?

Comment: checkout this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918186/scraping-text-from-unordered-lists-using-beautiful-soup-and-python

Comment: Getting the text is not really the problem. I am trying to get the xpath selector.

Comment: You need the xpath to locate the element in the first place, getting it again from the located element won't really help you.

Comment: Your not understanding my question. I have a UL and the XPATH for the UL. The UL is really long but i need selectors for Each element and i need the text to correspond to the selector. Is there a way to output the xpath selector for each element in a ul?

Comment: @Guy Possibly OP needs reverse engineering, Provide the _text_, extract the _xpath_, right AustinReedVlog?

Comment: @DebanjanB let's confirm from him....^.^

Comment: Sure that could work. How would you do that @debanjanB?

Comment: I revised the question so those of you can understand better what i need.